# Call function in one JavaScript file from another, in a setTimeout, and using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some code to detect a barcode scan. It was working when it was directly in an AngularJS controller. Since another controller needed to use that code also, I put the scan code in a separate JS file so they could both use it. My research showed that calling a JS file from another should work if I include them in the HTML page. I've done that. But after the scan code detects a scan, it tries to call a method on the other controller, but I get this error:

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'onBarcodeScan' is undefined

In barcodeScan.js:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    if (chars.length == 12) {
        var barcode = chars.join("");
        onBarcodeScan(barcode);  // Error occurs here
    }
    chars = [];
    pressed = false;
}, 500);
```

In my AngularJS controller:

```
var onBarcodeScan = function (barcode) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.state.userEnteredSubId = barcode;
        $scope.onSubmitSubId();
    });
}
```

What am I missing?

Note: My controller code is listed first in the index HTML page:

```
<script src="js/cassetteController.js"></script>
<script src="js/barcodeScan.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think `onBarcodeScan()` does not have public access. You need to expose it or you can better share it across multiple controllers by using an [angular service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

Comment: Why not you use **angular $broadcast** if it is working in angular controller. Otherwise read code in angular controller and set this result through plain JavaScript function in variable and in another controller get that result again. It will work.

Comment: Increase the timeout to ten seconds and see if this still happens. May be a loading issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a post that explained [using events in an AngularJS factory](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/04/angularjs-notifying-about-changes-from-services-to-controllers/). Here is the working code:

**Controller:**

```
scannerService.notify();

scannerService.subscribe($scope, function () {
    // Handle notification
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.state.userEnteredSubId = $rootScope.scan;
        $scope.onSubmitSubId();
    });
});
```

**Factory:**

```
app.factory('scannerService', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    var listenerAdded;

    return {
        subscribe: function (scope, callback) {
            var handler = $rootScope.$on('notifying-service-event', callback);
            scope.$on('$destroy', handler);
        },

        initialize: function () {
            if (listenerAdded) {
                return;
            }
            // From http://www.deadosaurus.com/detect-a-usb-barcode-scanner-with-javascript/:
            listenerAdded = true;
            var pressed = false;
            var chars = [];
            document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
                // Ignore this if the user is hitting enter, or any other non-number.
                if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
                    return;
                }
                // Only capture numbers, because a subId is all numbers.
                if (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) {
                    // Note: Theys keycodes are only for numbers along the top of the keyboard; the number pad uses a different range.
                    chars.push(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
                }
                console.log(event.keyCode + ":" + chars.join("|"));
                if (pressed == false) {
                    // The JS setTimeout method would cause us to have to use $scope.apply(). Instead, just use Angular's $timeout.
                    // http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        if (chars.length == 12) {
                            var barcode = chars.join("");
                            $rootScope.scan = barcode;
                            $rootScope.$emit('notifying-service-event');
                        }
                        chars = [];
                        pressed = false;
                    }, 500);
                }
                pressed = true;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```